# how to define html tag after each 5 iteration in foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, logic, iteration

I just want to know how to define HTML Tag `<br clear="all">`  after each 5 iteration in foreach loop here is my code

```
<?php
$i=1;    
foreach($videoEntries as $data){
?>
    <div class="item-main">
        <div class="item">
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="ratePopup(2)" title="<?php echo $data->video_name;?>">
        <div class="overlaid"></div>
        <img src="<?php echo $image_url;?>"  width="93" height="89"/>
        </a>
        </div>
        <p title="Trailer Name"><strong><?php echo $data->video_name;?></strong></p>
        <p title="Released Date"><?php echo $data->video_released_date;?></p>
    </div>
<?php 
    if($i == 5){
        echo "<br clear = 'all'>";    
    }
}
?>
```

Result Required or helps are definitely appricicated

```
12345
<br clear="all">
678910
<br clear="all">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$i=0;    
foreach($videoEntries as $data){
$i++;
?>
    <div class="item-main">
        <div class="item">
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="ratePopup(2)" title="<?php echo $data->video_name;?>">
        <div class="overlaid"></div>
        <img src="<?php echo $image_url;?>"  width="93" height="89"/>
        </a>
        </div>
        <p title="Trailer Name"><strong><?php echo $data->video_name;?></strong></p>
        <p title="Released Date"><?php echo $data->video_released_date;?></p>
    </div>
<?php 
    if($i == 5){
        echo "<br clear = 'all'>";  
        $i=0;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanx for sharing your experience with me

Comment: Every programer sould learn to do $i % 5, it is just too damn simple and usefull.   Doing what is proposed here create a unnecesary need to mantain $i inside the 0 5 range. Thats asking for trouble.

Comment: @tei - so is ++$i==5, its not rocket science...the person maintaining the codebase should take care of that.

Comment: Too. Many. Moving. Parts.   Anyway I don't want to stress my point. I am just adding my opinion here.

Answer (score 4):

You can change:

```
if($i == 5){
    echo "<br clear = 'all'>";    
}
```

to

```
if(!($i % 5)){
    echo "<br clear = 'all'>";    
}
```

Comment: thanx for sharing your experience with me

Answer (score 1):

try this: Assuming your array index is not set to something strange.

```
foreach ($videoEntries as $index=>$data) {
  if ($index % 5 == 0) {
    echo "<BR>";
  }
}
```

Comment: That'll include it for all but the multiples of 5.

Comment: @MichaelRushton Yea, u caught me seconds before I posted my edit

Comment: @Churk Thanx for sharing your experience with me

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($videoEntries as $data){
    $i++;
    ?>

<?php 
    if(($i % 5) == 0){
        echo "<br clear = 'all'>";  
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanx for sharing your experience with me

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete the examples...

Whenever you need the index of the loop, you can use the `for` loop instead (assuming it's an array). The `foreach` loop was invented for convenience, when you don't need the index.

```
for ($index = 0; $index < count(videoEntries); $index++)
{
  $data = $videoEntries[$index];
  ...
  if(($index % 5) == 0)
  {
    echo "<br clear = 'all'>";    
  }
}
```