# PHP - Foreach loop that limits 3 items each row

Tags: php

I'm retrieving my items from Exact and displaying them usuing a PHP loop. However, i want to put a HTML tag (br) after every 3 items.

Is there a possibility to do this? My current code:

```
<?php
    $glas = getGLAccounts($search);
    $count = 0

    foreach($glas as $gla) {
        $count++;
        echo "<tr><td><a href='glaccountedit.php?glaccount=".$gla['ID']."'>".$gla['Code']." </a></td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$gla['Description']."</td></tr>";

        if ($count == 3) {
            echo "</br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

However, this isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992396/how-to-define-html-tag-after-each-5-iteration-in-foreach-loop

Comment: `if($count % 3 == 0)` Use the modulo operator.

Comment: You need to reset the counter to start over

Comment: You don't reset your counter. Inside `if ($count == 3) {` add `$count = 0`. But I think @nicovank solution is way better.

Answer (score 3):

Your code will put `<br>` only once.
If you need to put after each three items you need to reset your variable:

```
if ($count == 3) {
    $count = 0;
    echo "</br>";
}
```

or change condition:

```
if ($count%3 === 0) {
    echo "</br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because your Count isn't reset. If `count == 3`, it will do a `<br>` but after this, count is again increased. So `count` will be 4, 5, 6, 7, etc and never again be `true` for `count == 3`

```
<?php
$glas = getGLAccounts($search);
$count = 0

foreach($glas as $gla) {
    $count++;
    echo "<tr><td><a href='glaccountedit.php?glaccount=".$gla['ID']."'>".$gla['Code']." </a></td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$gla['Description']."</td></tr>";
    if ($count == 3) {
        $count = 0;
        echo "</br>";
    }
}
?>
```